# Python: Given a 2-D array, return True is every number in array is a power of two, 0, and greater than 2000. No imported libraries

Tags: python, arrays, computer-science

`Python`: Given a 2-D `array`, create a function that will return `True` if every number in array is a power of two, 0 and greater than 200. No imported libraries.

Ex:

```
board = [[0,1,0,2],[0,0,2,4],[0,7,2001,0]] 
return False
```

--

```
def is_data(board):
    col= len(board[0])
    row= len(board)
    for c in range(col):
        for r in range(row):
            n= int(board[r][c])
            if n > 2000:
                return False
            else:
                while isinstance(n, int) == True:
                    if n % 2 != 1:
                        if isinstance(n, float):
                            return False
                            break
                        else:
                            n = n//2                  
    return True
```

Comment: Put four spaces in front of code-blocks, or wrap them with triple backticks `

Answer (score -1):

floor division isn't powers-of-two.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_oper_floordiv

```
def power_of_two( num ):
    while num > 1:  num /= 2
    if num == 1:  return True
    else:  return False

print(  power_of_two( 7 )  )
print(  power_of_two( 92 )  )
print(  power_of_two( 128 )  )
print(  power_of_two( 4096 )  )
```

Output:

```
False  
False  
True  
True
```